# arm-none-eabi-gcc does it support #pragma pack(n)

Tags: c, gcc, arm, pragma

I usually use `__attribute__...` packing but actually I port an embedded STM32 project from he IAR to gcc. My question is if gcc supports those pragmas or they are just ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC supports them (verified with [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7yElaV)) and have since at least [GCC 4.4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html).